# Windows scheduled task python read file when computer locked

Tags: python, windows, taskscheduler

I am very new to Python 3. I have written a script and used pyinstaller to convert it to an EXE. The script attempts to read from a text file named file.txt in the same directory as the EXE. This works just fine when running the EXE from task scheduler while the workstation is logged in and not locked. However, if I try to run the EXE from task scheduler with the user logged in and the workstation locked, I get the error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'.
```

This is my python simplified down to the current error (literally just put this in a new python file and ran it the same way and get the same error):

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as myfile:
    readfile = myfile.read()
print(readfile)
```

I have tried to search for this problem, but all I can find is how to lock/unlock a workstation with python or how to lock/unlock a file with python.

I am fairly certain this isn't a python problem and may just be an intended effect of using task scheduler when the station is locked but I am hoping there is a setting I can change to allow access to files when the workstation is locked or something else.

Comment: Under task properties -> General -> Security options, make sure "Run whether user is logged on or not" is selected. Also in Security options, make sure the right user is running the task - it may not be finding the file bc it doesn't have access to it.

Comment: @Leo I changed to "Run whether user is logged on or not" and double checked user running it. I also checked "Run with highest priveleges". Unfortunately, I am still getting the error.

Comment: do you get the same error when running the task manually from task scheduler? If so, you may be starting the script in the wrong directory, which you can change from Properties->Actions->Double-click your action->"Start in (optional)".

Comment: @Leo Thank you! That was it. Problem solved. Since this is in a comment and not an answer I'm not sure how to upvote/mark as answer for you. This is my first question on stackoverflow. If you make an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file may not be accessible by the script for the following reasons related to how the task is configured:

1. The task is not configured to run without the user being logged
   on. Fix: Task properties -> General -> Security options, make sure
   "Run whether user is logged on or not" is selected. Also make sure
   that the right user is running the task.
2. The task may be starting in the wrong directory. Fix: Task
   properties -> Actions -> Double-click your action -> "Start in
   (optional)", put in the correct starting directory.